# Subsequence implicate bounded and closed set

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

I've been thinking about that problem for a long time, now it is right time to ask!

Problem:

> Proof that if  $ K \subset \mathbb{R}^{d} $ is such a set that every sequence with elements in $ K $ include subsequence converge to element from $ K $, than $K$ is closed bounded  and closed set

Honestly I made few problems from that topic but I still dont have any idea how to do that proof. Please help!

Greetings:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $K$ was not bounded then for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ you had an $x_n \in K$ with $\vert x_n \vert > n$. Then the sequence $(x_n)_n$ would be diverging to $\infty$ and thus had no convergent subsequence. If $K$ was not closed then there would be an $x \in \bar{K}\setminus K$ and for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ you had an $x_n \in K$ with $\vert x_n -x \vert < \frac 1 n$. Then the sequence $(x_n)_n$ would be converging to $x$ and so would every subsequence. But since $x \notin K$ there would be no convergent subsequence with limit in $K$.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I don't clearly understand what $ (x_n)_n $ means? Would you be so kind as to clearify it for me?

Comment: $(x_n)_n$ is a short writing for $\left(x_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ or sometimes $\left\{x_n\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and denotes a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

To show that it is closed, take an arbitrary converging sequence $\{ \mathbf{a}_n \} \subseteq K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ with limit $\mathbf{p} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then there exists a subsequence $\{ \mathbf{a}_{n_j} \}$ of $\{ \mathbf{a}_n \}$ which converges to a limit in $K$, by assumption. But since $\{\mathbf{a}_n \}$ is convergent, the subsequence converges to the same limit. Hence $\mathbf{p} \in K$ and since the sequence was given arbitrarily, we conclude that $K$ is closed.

For the boundedness, you can look at Zardo's answer.